# Why does a SVG line disappear when I apply a SVG linearGradient?

Tags: javascript, svg

Update: Gets weirder. If the line is horizontal it disappears, but if it has any slope at all, it shows up just fine. Look at id="horizontalNoShow" if you change it so y1 and y2 are not equal, it will render.

I think this is a bug but not sure. Happens in Chrome and Safari. Trying to add an SVG linearGradient to a line.

I can add it to all other shapes, but when I add it to the line, the line disappears. Still shows up in the DOM, but just not getting rendered for some reason?

I have a purple line that shows up great. I have a rectangle with a gradient stroke that shows up great. But when I combine the gradient stroke with the line, it doesn't show up.

```html
    <svg width="" height="">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="FirstGradient" >
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FF00FF"/>
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFFF00"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <line id="someSlopeShow" x1="50" y1="70" x2="250" y2="71"
        stroke="url('#FirstGradient')"
        stroke-width="6"
      />
      <line id="horizontalNoShow" x1="55" y1="90" x2="255" y2="90"
        stroke="url('#FirstGradient')"
        stroke-width="6"
      />
      <rect id="exampleTwoRectSVG"
        x="10" y="10"
        width="200" height="100"
        stroke="url(#FirstGradient)"
        stroke-width="15"
        fill='transparent'
        stroke-dasharray="110 20"
      />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. The spec for **linearGradient** show that is uses an object bounding box. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits

However in the last paragraph:

> "Keyword objectBoundingBox should not be used when the geometry of the
> applicable element has no width or no height, **such as the case of a
> horizontal or vertical line, even when the line has actual thickness
> when viewed due to having a non-zero stroke width since stroke width
> is ignored for bounding box calculations**. When the geometry of the
> applicable element has no width or height and objectBoundingBox is
> specified, then the given effect (e.g., a gradient or a filter) will
> be ignored."

This makes sense since the box needs an area to work. And a horizontal line doesn’t have any area.   A hacky fix is you can fix it by adding .001 to your coordinates to give it a tiny bit of area.

```html
<svg width="" height="">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="FirstGradient" >
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FF00FF"/>
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFFF00"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <line id="horizontalNoShow" x1="55" y1="90" x2="255" y2="90.001"
        stroke="url('#FirstGradient')"
        stroke-width="6"
      />
</svg>
```

If I understand this correctly it means that none of the following features:

1. linearGradient
2. radialGradient
3. pattern
4. clipPath
5. mask
6. filter

will work if your line is horizontal or vertical.

I had a hard time finding the answer on StackOverFlow because I didn't realize it was the horizontal or vertical line that caused the issue.

These questions cover those well: [How to add a linearGradient to a vertical SVG line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997530/how-to-add-a-lineargradient-to-a-vertical-svg-line)

[SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display if vertical or horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight) (this question name isn't great. Straight couldn't mean a lot of things.)

SVG Masks also don't work on vertical or horizontal lines: [SVG Mask makes line disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475396/svg-mask-makes-line-disappear)

feDropshadows also don't work on vertical or horizontal lines:  [Adding feDropShadow to a vertical line in SVG makes it disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758565/adding-fedropshadow-to-a-vertical-line-in-svg-makes-it-disappear)